# Does google grant the ability to reach a result's preview snippet on a webpage?

Tags: google-search

When searching on Google, results will usually have a snippet of text under them that contain a part of the information I'm looking for.  However, visiting the result's webpage, that text may be impossible to find, or at least rather difficult, as many websites don't load text for ctrl+f searching until you scroll to that point.

Does google give the ability to reach this snippet in it's context on the page without needing to navigate to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does google give the ability to reach this snippet in it's context on
> the page without needing to navigate to it?

Not that I have seen and I use Google a lot (like many people).

If the research is for myself and the snippet is helpful, I use it and move on.

It the research needs to be supported (here for example), I open the page and search for the snippet.

I often find the snippet and sometimes do not because the snippet may be buried in a sub-link of the article.

Sometimes I just search a different way to get the page with the snippet I need.

Long answer to No, google does not give the ability to reach this snippet in it's context on the page without needing to navigate to it.